# How to perform random and periodic sampling / data collection of sensors in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, accelerometer, sensors, android-sensors

Android supports many sensors and the API supports periodic sampling i.e. I can sample the sensor data at every specified sampling time. Ideally, the periodic sampling is useful, but often it is unnecessary to continuously read a  sensor say the accelerometer when the phone is not vibrating for a long duration (e.g. during charging). I want to read the data of accelerometer randomly, where the sampling frequency is not fixed i.e. the duration between two samples is random. How do I do that ?

I tried the following code for reading the accelerometer data:

```
final  public SensorEventListener listener=new SensorEventListener() {

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "in sensor changed");
      if (e.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        double netForce=e.values[0]*e.values[0];

        netForce+=e.values[1]*e.values[1];
        netForce+=e.values[2]*e.values[2];

        AccelX=e.values[0];
        AccelY=e.values[1];
        AccelZ=e.values[2];

        message_acc= String.valueOf(AccelX)+","+String.valueOf(AccelY)+","+String.valueOf(AccelZ);

        Log.d(TAG, message_acc);

        //check if the phone is shaking
        if (threshold<netForce) {
          isShaking();
        }
        else {
          isNotShaking();
        }
      }

    }
```

This method is called in a thread, which is called periodically. In the above code, the API allows to collect the data when ever there is change in the data. My doubt is, is this approach a periodic data collection for a given sampling period? How do I deterministically specify the period of sampling ?

Secondly, If I want to perform random data collection, should it be done at the thread level, I mean, call/schedule the above method randomly? Any pointers to implement this or better ways to achieve this?